# How can I change my Apple ID password on my iPad 2?

Tags: ipad, password, apple-id

I just upgraded my iPad 2 to iOS 6. I am trying to access the App Store for the very first time ever (trying to get the free iBooks app). It keeps telling me I'm using the wrong password. I did not enter a password during the upgrade to iOS 6.

I think the problem has to do with the fact that the original password I entered (in iOS 5) is still stored somewhere on the iPad 2 because, using my notebook computer (not a Mac), I can sign on to Apple ID maintenance site using the new password I set up there.

I tried setting my Apple ID on the web (via my notebook) to the one I think is saved on my iPad 2, but it says it's not complex enough (it had two identical characters in a row).

How do I change the Apple ID password that (I think) is stored on the iPad 2?

I have made a few changes to the iPad settings, but not many because I am just starting to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to settings > iTunes & App Stores > Apple ID: Select sign out, that will clear your stored password...Then you can enter the proper information.